# How to check programatically whether a comment is new?

Tags: 7, hooks, comments

I'd like to make some changes to a **new** comment programatically. I'm using the following code:

```
function MYMODULE_comment_presave($comment) {
    $user = user_load($comment->uid);
    $uid = $user->uid;
    // if ($comment->is_new) {
        $comment->field_image['und'][0]['fid'] = $user->field_image['und'][0]['fid'];
        }
    // }
}
```

I don't know how I can check whether the comment that's about to be saved is new or edited. `$comment->is_new` doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [hook_comment_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_insert/7) instead, that should work.

Comment: You'd have to let me know what your logic is inside the hooks, then :)

Comment: So, basically, you're trying to display the user avatars on the comments? Try looking into the file_load function. You can probably do this in the comment template file, rather than saving it to the comment entity, as well. In order to do something to new comments only, you'd use hook_comment_insert(), though!

Comment: Indeed, that's what I'm trying to do (see: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104123/how-to-add-custom-user-fields-to-their-comments and http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104158/how-to-change-an-image-field-to-a-certain-fid-programatically). Maybe `file_load` can help me in solving the second question. In this case, however, `hook_comment_insert` really doesn't save any edits to the comment: the field may be an image field, integer field or whatever.

Comment: hook_comment_insert doesn't execute on updates, it is only executed when you insert a new comment. To print the avatar, see my comment on your other question :)